# Formatting SQL output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written an SQL Server procedure that I would like to have print the department name and students name (in a numbered list) that belong to the department.

The formatting should look like the attached sample snippet and there are two columns involved (students and departments)

The below code is what I have so far - information is mostly correct but the formatting is off and the print statement does not run.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pro_depart    
AS    
BEGIN

PRINT '************Procedure pro_department_report************'

SELECT (dd.DNAME) AS Department, STRING_AGG(ss.sname, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ss.sname DESC) AS Students
FROM STUDENT s
JOIN DEPARTMENT d ON dd.DEPTid = ss.DEPT_ID
GROUP BY dd.DNAME
ORDER BY d.DNAME ASC;

END
```

[image]

Comment: How are you running the stored procedure? If it is in Management Studio, the output of the PRINT statements is in the Messages tab, not the Results tab

Comment: I am running this from Microsoft SQL server management studio using Exec pro_depart;
(and I do see it under this tab)
I would like to have the print output in the results tab but not sure how to rework the code to accomplish this.

Comment: if you need output result as print ,  you need a cursor on departments , in each loop , at the top of loop print out the title of department then get the select all students in that department and build your print statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a grouping statement with a `rollup` clause?

**Sample data**

```
create table department
(
  deptId int,
  name nvarchar(20)
);

insert into department (deptId, name) values
(1, 'Overachievers'),
(2, 'Some department'),
(3, 'Weird group');

create table student
(
  deptId int,
  name nvarchar(20)
);

insert into student (deptId, name) values
(1, 'A. Alison'),
(2, 'B. Barnes'),
(2, 'C. Caldwell'),
(3, 'D. Duncan');
```

**Solution**

If some if these functions are new, then you can look them up in the documentation ([with rollup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql), [grouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-transact-sql), [coalesce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql)). Add `, grouping(d.name), grouping(s.name)` to the `select` field list to see where some ranges and sorts are coming from.

```
select coalesce(s.name, '***' + d.name + '***') as Report
from department d
join student s
  on s.deptId = d.deptId
group by d.name, s.name with rollup
having grouping(d.name) = 0
order by d.name, grouping(s.name) desc;
```

**Result**

Yes, every line is a separate row in the SSMS result tab, but you can copy-paste the rows to your favorite text editor and get line breaks after each row (as intended).

```
Report
---------------------
***Overachievers***
A. Alison
***Some department***
B. Barnes
C. Caldwell
***Weird group***
D. Duncan
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=be1459a280d224d35be269a9b58a1994) to see it in action.